# A property about matrices with precisely three eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is a symmetric matrix all of whose entries are from $\{0,1\}$ and suppose further that the all ones vector $\vec{1}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ for the eigenvalue $k.$ In addition suppose that $A$ has precisely two additional eigenvalues $\lambda \ne \mu.$ In some notes that I am currently reading it say that if $v$ is a vector orthogonal to $\vec{1}$ then $$(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I) \cdot v = 0.$$

I have a bit of a hard time understanding why is this true?  Can someone give a proof/short explanation?

Comment: Try to show that $v$ is a linear combination of eigenvectors for the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Comment: You will need to assume that neither $\lambda$ nor $\mu$ is equal to $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ is symmetric, hence we have a decomposition

$$V = \operatorname{ker}(A-kI) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(A-\lambda I) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(A-\mu I)$$

with the sum not only being direct, but also orthogonal. Hence any vector orthogonal to $\vec 1$ is contained in $\operatorname{ker}(A-\lambda I) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(A-\mu I)$ and of course we have

$$(A-\lambda I)(A-\mu I)(\operatorname{ker}(A-\lambda I) \oplus \operatorname{ker}(A-\mu I))=0.$$

Comment: Don't you also need to show that $\ker(A-kI)$ is $1$-dimensional? Otherwise you would have some other $k$-eigenvector orthogonal to $\vec{1}$.